# What code do I use for this popup window feature that I found on this template?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was looking at the following [template](https://html5up.net/dimension) for a website. Whenever one clicks on one of the buttons "Intro, Work, About, Contact" a "popup" window opens. I was wondering if you knew how I can add something similar to this to a website.

I tried to download the template and study the code but I got lost.

Comment: https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fhtml5up.net%2fdimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The concept to this is simple:

1. User clicks the nav link that is linked to content
2. The linked content shows in popup
3. Clicking close will hide linked content.

#### The control of content is:

- CSS controls sizing and placement of all elements at all breakpoints.
- JS controls the showing/hiding of popup content
- HTML contains all content, hidden or shown.

In saying that, here is a basic reproduction of your example link. There's
a thousand ways to skin this cat, and this is one. The animation can come from either JS or CSS, just not sure what you're going for. I prefer CSS as it's easier to track, at least for me.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li');
const contentBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.content-block-container > div');
const closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.close-content');

navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
  navLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const targetId = navLink.dataset.target;

    contentBlocks.forEach(contentBlock => {
      contentBlock.classList.remove('active');

      if (contentBlock.id === targetId) {
        contentBlock.classList.add('active');
      }
    });
  });
});

closeButtons.forEach(closeButton => {
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    contentBlocks.forEach(contentBlock => {
      contentBlock.classList.remove('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.content-block-container {
  position: relative;
}
.content-block {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content-block.active {
  display: block;
}

.inner {
  color: #000;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin: 3rem auto 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.close-content {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li data-target="content-1">Trigger for Content 1</li>
    <li data-target="content-2">Trigger for Content 2</li>
    <li data-target="content-3">Trigger for Content 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="content-block-container">
  <div class="content-block" id="content-1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="close-content">CLOSE</div>
      <h3>Content 1</h3>
      This div has an id of content-1. The trigger has an href of #content-1.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-block" id="content-2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="close-content">CLOSE</div>
      <h3>Content 2</h3>
      This div has an id of content-2. The trigger has an href of #content-2.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-block" id="content-3">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="close-content">CLOSE</div>
      <h3>Content 3</h3>
      This div has an id of content-3. The trigger has an href of #content-3.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

process for what you want.